# Gitlab-CI: how to make one task start when another one finishes

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab-ci

GitLab CI in my project has three stages (test, build, deploy). Some tasks run always and some only manually. In the deploy stage, I have these two GitLab CI tasks:

```
A:
  stage: deploy
  when: manual
  script:
    - echo "Deploy A"
  only:
  - master

B:
  stage: deploy
  when: manual
  script:
    - echo "Deploy B"
  only:
  - master
```

How can I make task B automatically start when task A finishes? Task A can be started manually but B should start automatically when task A finishes.

Comment: You should probably look for the answer here:
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually possible (see [here](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/merge_requests/9585)), but you need to put job B in a different stage, and set allow_failure to false in job A. So try with:

```
stages:
  - deploy
  - second-deploy

A:
  stage: deploy
  when: manual
  allow_failure: false
  script:
    - echo "Deploy A"
  only:
  - master

B:
  stage: second-deploy
  script:
    - echo "Deploy B"
  only:
  - master
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `needs` keyword in the second task, like so:

```yaml
stages:
  - deployA
  - deployB

A:
  stage: deployA
  when: manual
  script:
    - echo "Deploy A"
  only:
  - master

B:
  stage: deployB
  needs: ["deployA"]
  script:
    - echo "Deploy B"
  only:
  - master
```